# Charger with burning smell

Tags: charger

The MacBook charger has frayed/ broken plastic near the connection to the box on the charger. It will only charge while in certain positions and gets hot and has a burning smell. How can I fix this? I'm hoping wrapping it with electric tape will be enough?

Comment: If it's burning, probably not a good idea. It could cause damage to your MacBook, injure you, or even possibly burn your house down.

Answer (score 1):

It's not worth the potential fire hazard. If you go to Apple.com and look at the reviews on the MacBook chargers, people are very frustrated with the need to replace the chargers so frequently due to wear exactly where you described it. I would highly recommend replacing the charger over repairing it.